# Calling view method in controller

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I want invoke view method in controller but I don't know how :) I sought like example, but I don't found it. Can I do that in this code ? whether I must build it anew ?
I use javafx and fxml technology( to build user interface ).

My view file ( it have gotoRegister() and gotoLogin() method ( i want to invoke them ))

```
public class FXMLExampleMVC extends Application{

    protected Parent root;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        gotoLogin();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome!");
        scene.getStylesheets().add(FXMLExampleMVC.class.getResource("cssforapp.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.show();
    }

    public void gotoRegister() throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RegisterFXML.fxml"));  
    }
    public void gotoLogin() throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);  
    }
}
```

My controller ( here i want invoke gotoRegister() method )

```
public class SampleController {

    public SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
    @FXML
    protected Text actiontarget;
    @FXML
    protected PasswordField passwordField;
    @FXML
    protected TextField loginField;

    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(){
        if((loginField.getText().equals(model.returnLogin()))&&(passwordField.getText().equals(model.returnPass())) ){
            actiontarget.setText("You have access !");
        } else {
           actiontarget.setText("Wrong data !"); 
        }

    }
    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonRegister() throws IOException{
        // 
       //Here I want to invoke gotoRegister
      //
    }
}
```

My question: Can I invoke gotoRegister ? or, maybe is other way to change fxml file ( from controller )?

Comment: N.B.: setting a field `root` wouldn't change content of your scene (this is now Java works). You need to call `scene.setRoot(root)` to achieve that. So better option would be storing `scene` as a field and directly calling `setRoot()` method with new root.

Comment: Thanks, I will use your solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this code in FXMLExampleMVC.java

```
private static FXMLExampleMVC instance;
public FXMLExampleMVC() {
           instance = this;
}
// static method to get instance of view
public static FXMLExampleMVC getInstance() {
        return instance;
}
```

and now you can call your view methods in controller like this

```
  @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonRegister() throws IOException{
        // 
       //Here I want to invoke gotoRegister
        FXMLExampleMVC.getInstance().gotoRegister();
    }
```

Comment: It's not working when the return type of the gotoRegister() method is not void. Can you please explain? Thank you.